# Smoothing CSS effects for a mousemove event in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to create a subtle effect in which a CSS gradient follows the movement of the cursor over the window.

The following code is working as I'd like, but the movement/animation is jerky and delayed. I'd like for it to be smoother.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.texgrad');
btn.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
});
```

```css
body {background:#000}

.ca.fullpage#top .texgrad {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.35;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(150%) brightness(100%);
  filter: contrast(150%) brightness(100%);
  background: radial-gradient( circle farthest-side at var(--x) var(--y), rgba(237, 242, 239, 0.15), transparent), url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 75 75' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cfilter id='noiseFilter'%3E%3CfeTurbulence type='fractalNoise' baseFrequency='10' numOctaves='6' stitchTiles='stitch'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' filter='url(%23noiseFilter)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<section class="ca fullpage" id="top">
  <div class="texgrad" style="--x: 100px; --y: 100px;"></div>
</section>
```

[DEMO](https://demo.dev.matmartin.studio)

Is there a better way to do this? Or is there something in my code that would cause this to happen?

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question instead of needing that external link. However there seems to be a typo in your SVG data string in the CSS. Please fix that so the code snippet can work here.  However, generally from what I see in your code and that working demo, what you are doing seems fine. I'm not sure there's a lot to be improved on here.

Comment: Works fine on demo link as well here

Comment: Thanks folks. Yeah it works but the movement's pretty clunky isn't it? @ChrisBarr I'm not sure what the typo you're referring to is? Happy to fix it but can you identify it?

Comment: Relax, there's no typo in SVG. What is your desired result? Are you building some kind of a spotlight effect over some content or something else?

Comment: Thanks @Kosh — Just a gentle subtle sheen for depth and focus. Nothing as front-line as a spotlight effect. Just want the background to have some texture and breathe a little.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Either someone else has fixed it or I had some issue loading it before. it works now.  I'm not seeing any clunkyness, it's smooth for me in Firefox and Chrome.  Chrome devtools shows me I get 57-59fps when I move the mouse around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To optimize this code you need to know [this](https://web.dev/rendering-performance/).

In JS, I moved `getBoundingClientRect` out of the `EventListener` as it seems to be the same on each `mousemove`, therefore it would be enough to get it once. Also it won't trigger consecutive re-flows here.

In CSS, changing `background` property causes re-paint and re-composition of the element. So I replaced the `radial-gradient` with a pseudo-element with `box-shadow` (imho, it's more simple but has the same effect; you may use the gradient though) and do `transform:translate3d()` instead to completely move the effect to the composition phase and to use GPU instead of CPU.

Hope this helps.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.texgrad');
let rect = btn.getBoundingClientRect();
btn.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000
}

.ca.fullpage#top .texgrad {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.35;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(150%) brightness(100%);
  filter: contrast(150%) brightness(100%);
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 75 75' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cfilter id='noiseFilter'%3E%3CfeTurbulence type='fractalNoise' baseFrequency='10' numOctaves='6' stitchTiles='stitch'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Crect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23noiseFilter)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.ca.fullpage#top .texgrad:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50vmax 15vmax rgb(237, 242, 239);
  will-change: transform;
  transform: translate3d(var(--x), var(--y), 0);
}
```

```html
<section class="ca fullpage" id="top">
  <div class="texgrad" style="--x: 100px; --y: 100px;"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. Really appreciate you taking the time to explain the whys and hows, too. Learning over here!